# How to install CorePlot framework correctly?

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode4, core-plot

I want to use CorePlot.framework in Mac OS X. However, I cannot install it correctly though it has costed me several hours.

I downloaded it (0.4 version) from google host site, and have tried to put CorePlot.framework  in "/Library/Frameworks/" or some other custom places.

I also have added it into "link binary and libraries". unfortunately, the compiler always cannot find "" .

Any one who have some experience can give me some advice to install and use it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you check the readme files, you can find the instructions as follows:

1. Copy the CorePlotHeaders to your Xcode project
2. Copy libCorePlotCocoaTouch.a to your Xcode project
3. Add to Other Linker Flags in your target build settings: -ObjC -all_load
4. Add the QuartzCore framework to the project.

To follow these instructions, create a new blank project and copy the folder (drag and drop) CorePlotHeaders into Xcode. When prompted, be sure to check "copy these files/folders to the source directory".

Next drag the libCorePlayCocoaTouch.a library in the same manner (again, select the checkbox). You should now have the .h files and the .a included in your project.

Now, select your project and choose the "Target" and in the 3rd tab "Build Settings" search for "Other Linker Flags" and add -"ObjC -all_load" without quotes.

Finally, add the QuartzCore framework to your project and you're done.

I've been working with CorePlot today and am rather impressed with it so far. It's not 100% comprehensive but it's good enough for what we need. If you get stuck, be sure to follow the readme instructions and double check everything is setup as needed. I didn't struggle with getting it set up unlike some other libraries so hopefully you should be able to get sorted with minimal fuss :)

Comment: thanks very much for your answer how to install it step by step:)

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you manage to get everything sorted :)